# FFMPEG multiple styles in .srt file

Tags: ffmpeg, webvtt, srt

I have an SRT file and want to change the background color and level of transparency for individual tracks. Is this possible, or would I have to adopt a more advanced format? Would this task even work in FFMPEG?

```
1
0:0:1,440 --> 0:0:1,970  Y1:20
<font color="#FF1F497D">{\an2}the settlement?</font>
2
0:0:2,640 --> 0:0:3,150  Y1:20
<font color="#FFC0504D">{\an2}Yes.</font>
3
0:0:3,740 --> 0:0:4,690  Y1:20
<font color="#FFFFFFFF">{\an2}Have you been waiting long?</font>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ASS format. It's more advanced and more complicated but it can do what you want.

[image]

You can use [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) to make or convert the subtitles.

Or `ffmpeg` can convert SRT to ASS and you can manually add [tags](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/).

```
ffmpeg -i input.srt output.ass
```

Example ASS file:

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayResX: 384
PlayResY: 288
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,16,&H00FFFFFF,&H00FFFFFF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,3,1,0,2,10,10,10,0

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:01.44,0:00:01.97,Default,,0,0,0,,{\c&H00FFFF&\3a&H80&\3c&HFF00FF&}the settlement?{\c}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:02.64,0:00:03.15,Default,,0,0,0,,{\c&H50C0FF&\3a&HA2&\3c&H00FF00&}Yes.{\c}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.74,0:00:04.69,Default,,0,0,0,,{\c&HFFFFFF&\3a&H80&\3c&HFF00FF&}Have you been waiting long?{\c}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should of clarified, when I said background color I meant as in the color of the rectangle the subtitles are in that's usually black.